# generar reportes HTML desde ASP.net

Tags: html, c#, asp

Buen día comunidad,

Recién me registro pues me doy cuenta de la gran cantidad de miembros activos que conforman ésta gran comunidad y que suelen ayudar.

Vengo buscando orientación ya que he explorado en diversos sitios sin obtener una información que cumpla con mis requerimientos.

Estoy buscando la posibilidad, de generar desde mi página asp diversos archivos html, mismos que contendrán texto estático, pero también dinámico, éste último consistente en una tabla con información extraída desde mi base de datos.

La idea es generar un reporte en HTML (más de uno), entrelazados, incluyendo imágenes ubicadas en el directorio de mi proyecto, así como estilos CSS. Todo dentro de una carpeta, misma que desearía comprimir en zip (ese es otro tema), y posteriormente enviar toda la estructura comprimida al cliente para su descarga.

Por lo anterior, pido me orienten la mejor forma de lograr lo ya mencionado, comenzando por la creación de los archivos HTML con información desde mi base de datos.

Les comento que estoy utilizando formularios web con página maestra, C# en Visual Studio 2019.

Gracias de antemano a quien pueda colaborarme.

Un saludo

Comment: Bienvenido/a al sitio, debes añadir lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento, de otra manera me temo que tú pregunta terminará cerrada, si tienes dudas puedes consultar el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomendaría utilizar un enfoque incremental.
Desde ASP.net es relativamente sencillo crear un archivo de texto y guardarlo. Puedes hacer lo mismo con un archivo html.
Podrías crear un componente en tu aplicación que genere el archivo en texto con tu base de datos y lo guarde como html en una carpeta que sea accesible por un controlador.
Acto seguido podrías generar una lógica en el controlador que reciba un parametro de tipo string que sería el nombre del archivo html que generaste y puedes devolverlo con

```
public ActionResult ObtenerReporte(String nombreReporte)
{
    return View(nombreReporte);
}
```

Si has guardado el archivo de texto como html dentro de la carpeta de views del controlador correspondiente, esa función de retorno les va a devolver ese archivo como una vista de aspnet normal, donde puedes linkear toda tu información, imágenes, etc.

Comment: Gracias amigo @Bryan Longa por su respuesta. A decir verdad, agradecería si me ejemplifica un poco mas su explicación que amablemente me brindaras, ya que no conozco muchos términos técnicos que ha empleado en su  respuesta. Así mismo, alcanzo a comprender que hace referencia a ASP MVC, pero estoy utilizando web forms con página maestra. Gracias nuevamente  por su ayuda.

Comment: Estimado para poder ayudarte más, necesitaría que seas más especifico en lo que requieres, ya que de hecho lo que estas consultando es bastante amplio, para lo cual he tratado de dar un respuesta que cubra la mayor parte de cosas pero al mismo tiempo también es una respuesta amplia.
¿Usted mismo va a codificar esa funcionalidad? En ese caso le recomendaría como le comenté el enfoque incremental, paso a paso, empezando por el guardado de un archivo de texto como prueba.html.
Puede encontrar mas info aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733832/save-file-from-a-byte-in-c-sharp-net-3-5